# How can I deal with “typedef”-style data types with a minimum of boilerplate?

Tags: haskell

I defined a custom data type that contains a single field:

```
import Data.Set (Set)

data GraphEdge a = GraphEdge (Set a)
```

Defining my own type feels more semantically correct but it leads to a lot of boilerplate in my functions. Any time I want to use the built-in `Set` functions I have to unwrap the inner set and later rewrap it:

```
import Data.Set (map)

modifyItemsSomehow :: Ord a => GraphEdge a -> GraphEdge a
modifyItemsSomehow (GraphEdge items) = GraphEdge $ Set.map someFunction items
```

This could be improved slightly by making it a record, like

```
import Data.Set (Set, map)

data GraphEdge a = GraphEdge { unGraphEdge :: Set a }

modifyItemsSomehow = GraphEdge . map someFunction . unGraphEdge
```

but this still feels far from ideal. What is the most idiomatic way to handle this kind of boilerplate when dealing with a user-defined data type that consists of a single field?

Comment: Any reason you're using `data` instead of `newtype`?

Comment: @Carl Nope, just ignorance :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before anything else, you should make sure to use `newtype` for single-field single-constructor types. `data` introduces runtime overhead and extra laziness, and prevents us from using the first two of the following techniques.

First, you can use [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#newtype-deriving) when possible:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Foo a = Foo a deriving (Eq, Show, Ord, Num)

foo :: Foo Int
foo = 0

bar :: Foo Int
bar = foo * 120
```

Second, you can use [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) to generally convert between newtype wrappings:

```
import Data.Coerce

newtype Foo a = Foo a
newtype Bar a = Bar a

a :: [(Foo (Bar Int), Foo ())]
a = [(Foo (Bar 0), Foo ())]

b :: [(Int, ())]
b = coerce a
```

Third, you can use [`iso`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html)-s from [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13) to concisely move operations over/under newtype constructors.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Control.Lens

newtype GraphEdge a = GraphEdge (Set a)
makePrisms ''GraphEdge

modifyItemsSomehow :: Ord a => GraphEdge a -> GraphEdge a
modifyItemsSomehow = _GraphEdge %~ Set.map someFunction
```

Comment: `lens` now offers (for 7.10+ only; don't know why not 7.8--could've been my mistake) `coerced :: forall s t a b. (Coercible s a, Coercible t b) => Iso s t a b`.

Comment: `lens` also offers the `Control.Lens.Wrapped` module for various forms of performing an operation under a newtype.